# Move branches, but do not overwrite modified files

Tags: git, branch, git-checkout, working-directory

I am in branch `wip` and want to move to branch `dev`. I have some not-committed changes in the working dir.

```
$ git checkout dev 
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        .idea/runConfigurations/celery_beat.xml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
```

Ok, I get it: that file won't merge. And I do not want to lose my changes to it. What I want is:

1. Checkout the dev branch
2. For the files that are not possible to get merged, keep the version in my working dir (do not try to merge)

Alternatively, I sometimes want this:

1. Checkout the dev branch
2. Do not overwrite any of the files which have changes in the working dir. That is, the non-comitted files that I have while in the `wip` branch should stay as they are, the rest of the working dir should be populated from the `dev` branch. A simple `git diff` will show me what changes I have after moving to the `dev` branch.

### EDIT

The way I would solve this now is:

1. `git status`
2. Get list of changed files
3. Copy those files somewhere outside the repo
4. `git checkout -- .`
5. `git checkout dev`
6. Get back those files into the repo
7. `git diff` gives me now the changes as compared to `dev`

Does `git` have a built-in mechanism to do this?

Comment: `.idea/` should have been ignored and not tracked by Git in the first place.

Comment: @ElpieKay not really related to the question, but the policy in my current customer is to track the editor files, so that development environments are available immediately by cloning the repo.

Comment: Then the policy is not reasonable. If all team members should use the same development environments, why is your `.idea` different from `dev` and why can't you just discard your local changes to `.idea`? If every member is allowed to use his/her own environments, then why do you need to track `.idea`, which will obviously bring conflicts?

Comment: @ElpieKay Because I am upgrading the repo with new environment settings, and I will make it available to the rest of the team. Those changes are conflicting with the dev branch because, well, just because. But really, not related to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
#stash the changes to ".idea/runConfigurations/celery_beat.xml"
git stash

#switch to dev without conflicts or overwriting
git checkout dev

#restore ".idea/runConfigurations/celery_beat.xml" to the version before the switch
git checkout stash@{0} -- .idea/runConfigurations/celery_beat.xml

#now ".idea/runConfigurations/celery_beat.xml" is staged, in order to remove it from the index:
git reset HEAD -- .idea/runConfigurations/celery_beat.xml

#if you'd like to drop the stash entry
git stash drop
```

But still I have to say, it's not a good idea to track `.idea`.